# Как сделать неограниченный history

Tags: linux, bash

Очень часто требуется найти команду, которую использовал довольно длительное время назад, но  history обычно ограничен 2000 строк, как его сделать неограниченным или хотя бы существенно увеличить? Использую обычный bash

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/how-long-do-the-contents-of-the-bash-history-file-last

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

программа *bash* оперирует в данном случае двумя переменными окружения:

- `HISTSIZE` — максимальное количество запоминаемых команд в текущей сессии (по умолчанию, если нигде не переопределяется, равно `500`)
- `HISTFILESIZE` — максимальное количество команд (по умолчанию, если нигде не переопределяется, берётся из первой переменной), сохраняемых в файле истории (определяется переменной `HISTFILE`, обычно `~/.bash_history`) по окончании сессии (или после выполнения команды `history -a` или `history -w`)

как правило, эти две переменные переопределяются в файле `~/.bashrc`

---

чтобы не раздувать текущую историю до космических масштабов (а она ведь считывается каждым интерактивным процессом *bash*), я лично на своих рабочих компьютерах присваиваю обеим переменным значение `10000` (на месяц хватает) и делаю ежемесячную копию файла истории `~/.bash_history` (`~/.bash_history.дата`), добавив в свою пользовательскую таблицу `crontab` строку:

```
1 1 1 * * cp -a ${HOME}/.bash_history ${HOME}/.bash_history.$(/bin/date +"\%F")
```

в купе с переменной `HISTTIMEFORMAT` (у меня она равна `'%Y%m%d %H%M%S  '`) даёт неплохие результаты (благодаря тому, что она определена, в файле истории фиксируется и время выполнения команды).